# How do I pass data in timer to new ViewController (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, timer, swift3, viewcontroller, viewdidload

I know how to pass data to a new ViewController. The problem is that I can't seem to pass data from within a timer.

The following code works for one ViewController. I have tried multiple ways of splitting the code up into two view controllers. I have tried placing the timer in the SecondViewController. I have tried only passing the initial datePicker. I have tried placing functions inside of functions.

The current problem is that I can't pass totalSeconds because it's defined within the timer. If I initialize the function outside the timer, say at 0, it simply returns a value of 0. If I pass the datePicker, or date components, I run into a similar issue when I define the time intervals within the SecondViewController. For instance, the updateTimer function will not recognize the values passed into the SecondViewController's ViewDidLoad().

Any help is greatly appreciated. I simply want to place the strings in updateTimer() in a SecondViewController.

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var Output: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Output4: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Output3: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Output2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var timePicker: UIDatePicker!
    @IBOutlet weak var Output5: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Output6: UILabel!

    var birthDate = DateComponents()

    @IBAction func timePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {

    let tComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: (sender as AnyObject).date)
    birthDate.hour = tComponents.hour
    birthDate.minute = tComponents.minute
}

    @IBAction func datePickerChanged(_ sender: Any) {
    let components = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: (sender as AnyObject).date)
    birthDate.year = components.year
    birthDate.month = components.month
    birthDate.day = components.day
}

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.updateTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

    func updateTimer(){
    let now = Date()

    let birthDay = userCalendar.date(from: birthDate)!

    let totalSeconds = Int(now.timeIntervalSince(birthDay))

    let totalMinutes = userCalendar.dateComponents([.minute], from: birthDay, to: now)

    let totalHours = userCalendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: birthDay, to: now)

    let totalDays = userCalendar.dateComponents([.day], from: birthDay, to: now)

    let totalWeeks = userCalendar.dateComponents([.weekOfYear],from: birthDay, to: now)

    let totalMonths = userCalendar.dateComponents([.month], from: birthDay, to: now)

    Output.text = String(totalSeconds)
    if totalMinutes.minute != nil {
        Output2.text = String(totalMinutes.minute!)
    }
    if totalHours.hour != nil {
        Output3.text = String(totalHours.hour!)
    }
    if totalDays.day != nil{
        Output4.text = String(totalDays.day!)
    }
    if totalWeeks.weekOfYear != nil{
        Output5.text = String(totalWeeks.weekOfYear!)
    }
    if totalMonths.month != nil{
        Output6.text = String(totalMonths.month!)
    }

}
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    updateTimer()
    let secondsController = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
    secondsController.finalSeconds = totalSeconds
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@CJW ,
```

> Are you aware of Protocols & Delegate concept.
>       You can easily fix above issue using delegates & protocols.

1.Create a Protocol in your first viewcontroller class as

```
protocol TimerUpdateDelegate {
    func updateTotalSeconds(_ iTotalSeconds : Int)
}
```

2.Create variable for delegate as

```
var delegate : TimerUpdateDelegate?
```

3.Now Add below line of code in your `updateTimer` method of first view controller.

```
        if self.delegate != nil 
         {self.delegate?.updateTotalSeconds(totalSeconds)}
```

in above line of code that `totalSeconds` will be your calculated value in self `updateTimer` function as parameter.

4.Now import delegate in your second viewcontroller class as,

```
         class ViewController: UIViewController,TimerUpdateDelegate {}
```

5.In ViewDidload method add below set of line:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  firstViewController.delegate = self
  }
```

6.Define TimerUpdateDelegate methods in your second class view controller :

```
    func updateTotalSeconds(_ iTotalSeconds : Int)
            {
                self.finalSeconds = iTotalSeconds
            }
```

I hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much. Will try. New to programming and iOS, so I haven't heard about protocols and delegates.